# Can template-haskell be used to generate quasi-quotes?

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

A project that I'm currently working on makes extensive use of `persistent`. Instead of `persistent`'s quasi-quoted syntax to specify models, I would like to use json. Right now, I use a script to generate the quasiquote which `persistent` expects using `simple-templates`. That adds a rather awkward step in the workflow. Can this be avoided using `template-haskell`?

This is currently generated by the script :

```
-- File : ProjSpecific.Models

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
[persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]
```

This is how I would ideally like to do it :

```
-- File : ProjSpecific.Config

import Data.Aeson.QQ
import Data.Aeson (Value)

models :: Value
models = [aesonQQ| {some json encoding of above models} |]
```

And

```
-- File : ProjSpecific.Models

complie time logic to generate the persistent models
```

Any ideas on how this can be done or is there a better way to accompilsh what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be relatively painless. You'd essentially want to use the [quoteExp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.9.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html#v:quoteExp) field from `persistLowerCase`, which will give you a function of type `String -> Q Exp`. Use your preprocessor to convert JSON into the expected syntax, and then pass it to the function.